# Why does intellij's code completion not suggest flutter: files?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I have set up IntelliJ for Flutter developement (installed all plugins and the sdk, etc.) but code completion is not working for flutter: ,
just for dart: , but the code works fine.

I tried clearing cache and reinstalling the flutter sdk.

[(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VZnp.png)

Comment: Have you installed Flutter and Dart pluggin?

Comment: @AasharWahla yes, i have included that in the original post now, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Code completion is powered by Dart SDK; I'd suggest submitting a ticket to either https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues or https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues; looks related to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45345